# jsTree 3 - select next / previous node of dynamically loaded tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a jsTree with lazy loading. I want to be able to select the next and previous nodes using an external function. The api suggests tree.get_next_dom() but this only seem to work on nodes that have already been loaded, not ones that may require loading first.

```
$("[href='#next']").click(function () {
    var tree = $('#container').jstree(true),
        curr = tree.get_selected(false);
    tree.deselect_all();
    var n = tree.get_next_dom(curr);
    tree.select_node(n);
});
```

see full fiddle for a example showing the lazy load .. 
http://jsfiddle.net/6L7twnka/3/

So "next" would see if the node had children and then expand it, loading if required. Previous would have to look at get_prev_dom and then expand it and then possibly expand all the last nodes inside it (recursively) in order to then put the selection on the most immediately previous node. I got a bit lost trying to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've already solved, but I leave here a suggestion.
After the method call "tree.deselect_all ();" you invoke the "tree.open_all ()" method.

```
$ ("[href = '# next']"). click (function () {
    var tree = $ ('# container'). jstree (true)
    curr = tree.get_selected (false);
    tree.deselect_all ();
    tree.open_all ();
    var n = tree.get_next_dom (curr);
    tree.select_node (n);
});
```

Sincerely,

Charles Oliveira

Comment: When stepping *backwards* through the tree (using get_prev_dom), it should wait until the previous node is expanded, then get the item directly above the selected (which should be the last node loaded). It gets the next sibling instead (with strict set either way). Or I'm reading the documentation wrong.